# Constraint forces and the Lagrangian

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, free-body-diagram, constrained-dynamics

Consider a scenario where a particle is placed on the surface of a dome-shaped object (a hemisphere) and moves on the surface of the dome due to gravity. My question was, how do I find the equation of motion of the particle using Lagrangian mechanics (assuming the motion is two-dimensional and looks something like Fig 1)?

[image: Fig 1]

I found two methods:

**Method 1**

In the first method, the Lagrangian was given by

$$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^{2}+r^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2})-mgr\cos {\theta}-V(r)$$

where $V(r)$ is the potential responsible for preventing the particle from sinking into the sphere (the potential responsible for the normal force).

The E-L equations yield:
$$mr^{2}\ddot{\theta}+2mr\dot{r}\dot{\theta}=mgr\sin {\theta}$$
$$m\ddot{r}=mr\dot{\theta}^{2}-mg\cos{\theta}-V'(r).$$

Since the normal force $N=-V'(r)$ ensures that $r(t)=R$ ($R$ is the radius of the hemisphere), we arrive at the equations:

$$\ddot{\theta}=\frac{g}{R}\sin{\theta}$$
$$N=mg\cos{\theta}-mR\dot{\theta}^{2}.$$

**Method 2**

The second method directly imposes the constraint $r=R$ and does not keep any terms in the Lagrangian corresponding to the Normal force:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}mR^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2}-mgR\cos {\theta}$$

The E-L equation yields:

$$\ddot{\theta}=\frac{g}{R}\sin{\theta}.$$

**My questions**

1. How can both methods yield the same equation of motion? Please give a mathematical reason for this.
2. How can the second method be valid if it does not incorporate the Normal force (the constraint force) into the Lagrangian?

Note: This is the first time I am learning how to use the Lagragian. Please do not blow me away with *too much* mathematics. (I do not know what Lagrange multipliers, generalized coordinates, generalized forces, etc., and other concepts in Lagrangian formalism.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460713/2451

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you are describing the same system, i.e. a particle that is constrained to $r=R$ and is subject to gravity. More generally, when dealing with [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) (i.e., when you can express the constraint with a function of the variables equated to zero, in our case $f(r, \theta)=r-R=0$), you can either just constrain the respective degree of freedom (in our case, $r$), or leave it as is and add a constraining force, which will be determined after obtaining the equations of motion by then applying the constraint equation (in our case $r-R=0$). This second method is only used when you are interested in obtaining these constraining forces and is related to Lagrange multipliers. Do not be scared of them, they really are not mathematically complicated, [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/570e7b14e707ebd28d391286/t/58089d741b631b83fe943727/1476959606817/classical-6.pdf) you have a better explanation together with a few examples of this second method in action, including a similar problem to yours.

Answer (score 1):

1. They give the same equations of motion because it doesn't matter where you apply the constraint $r(t) = R$. This is because $r$ is not a dynamical degree of freedom; therefore it is irrelevant where you impose the constraint (at the level of lagrangian or the equations of motion).
2. The normal force is a reactionary force and doesn't contribute to the dynamics. As the contsraint implies, the only relevant motion is in the direction of $\theta$. What this means is that the normal force in this case just imposes the constraint and adds the necessary force for the object to stay at radius $r = R$ throughout its journey.

There is another way to solve these types of systems with constraints. You include a lagrange multiplier into your lagrangian which helps enfore the constraint. You can find more about this in David Morin's book (I assume that's where the problem is from). Hope this helps!